# Script isn't writing anything after $ to text file

Tags: bash, echo, currency

In a bash script I have it is supposed to write certain lines to a file.
This is what it supposed to write:

```
echo "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/forklift/forklift-workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

and this is what it writes in the file:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/forklift/forklift-workspace:
```

how do I fix this?
I'm using Ubuntu

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: try using the `'` and not the `"` as delimiter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: @Barmar I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Comment: No apology necessary. If you'd known that the problem was with the type of quotes, you wouldn't have asked the question, so you couldn't have known that it was a dupe of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected if the variable `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is not defined (or equal to "") when `echo` is called.  If I understand what you are trying to do, then you can just replace the double-quotes with single quote to prevent this behaviour.  Thus

```
echo 'export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/forklift/forklift-workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Should add the line

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/forklift/forklift-workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

to your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` in the string is being interpolated as a variable, but it doesn't exist in the environment so it just comes out blank.

It needs to be escaped with a `\`, like this:

```
echo "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/forklift/forklift-workspace:\$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

For more in-depth information on parameter expansion, this is pretty comprehensive: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html